# SFTP backup task got a network issue and cannot reconnect after on debian

Tags: networking, debian, logging, sftp

I have got a problem with a scheduled task in PHP on my debian server.
Every night, I send a backup of data from server S1 to server S2. The two server are dedicated server but not host at the same location.

The backup is composed of multiple files (from 300MB to 5GB) send with Net_SFTP from phpseclib, with multiple schedule timer between 0h and 4h to not take to much ressources on the network connection.

And every night, I have got issue with 3-4 files, with a network error during transfer (usualy when we reach 100k ms time so maybe a timeout), that is follow by retries that failed with no connection issue (in 0.1 ms, so very quick for a network issue). It can happen at any time during the night (3h14 today, 3h50 yesterday) and when it cut, all the files that was transfering at that moment got the exact same log (with only the time of transfer of the first try that change). It's never the same file, a file can failed 3 days in a row and work perfectly fine the rest of the week.

When I check the ressources consume on the network graph, I am not at the maximum of bandwith that the connection between S1 and S2 can handle.
When I ask for log at the host of S2, they didn't see anything and tell me to see system log on S2 to understand what happen.

I am root of S1 and S2, so I can check any log, but I don't know where to look (and what I search).

Comment: From the phpseclib side I'd enable logging. You can do that by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2)` and then, after the transfer fails, do `$sftp->getLog()`. Then post the results on github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib and let the author of phpseclib take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching in php error log, I find a notice :

PHP Notice:  Connection closed prematurely in /usr/share/php/Net/SSH2.php on line yyyy
PHP Notice:  Connection closed by server in /usr/share/php/Net/SSH2.php on line xxxx
PHP Notice:  Connection closed by server in /usr/share/php/Net/SSH2.php on line xxxx

In file SSH2.php, on line xxxx, I found that $this->fsock is not reset on connection Failure, the test if (!is_resource($this->fsock)) is still false, and then the fsockopen is not done again.

I set my Net_SFTP class on null, and do a new Net_SFTP() during the retry, and I Don't have this issue anymore (I still have network cut that I cannot identify but the retry work now).